# How do I create a shared folder after virtualization Windows 10 with VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: virtualbox, windows, wine, dropbox, guest-os

I have installed Ubuntu on my computer(moving from Mint). Everything is fast, secure and outright amazing.

But, I still need to use Windows for a few custom-built work applications. I tried using Wine but it doesn't work properly.

So, I had to install VirtualBox and install Windows 10 home on it.

I have installed all the necessary applications and everything seems to be working like a charm.

Now, I have to share a folder with both of these OS to optimize my workflow.

I am tired of using Dropbox.

Please, help me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*PS: Linux Ubuntu is the host and Windows 10 is the guest operating system.*

Answer (score 0):

Shared folders are a feature provided by [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html).